# Get JSON error when I try to delete an entry from MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

When I make a request from my client side to my backend (Springboot webflux) to delete a document from Mongo DB I get a JSON error. What am I missing?

My client side code:

```
 fetch("http://localhost:8080/shifts/deleteShift", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(UID),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setDeleteShift(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Server Side code:

Controller:

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping("/deleteShift")
    private Mono<Void> deleteShift(@RequestBody String ID) {
        return shiftService.deleteShift(ID);
    }
```

Service

```
 public Mono<Void> deleteShift(String ID){
        return this.shiftRepository.deleteById(ID);
    }
```

Repo Interface

```
@Repository
public interface ShiftRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Shift, String> {
}
```

Error
[image]

Comment: Can you share you code snippit of `Editshifts.tsx`

Comment: The client side code given is from Editshifts.tsx. I am thinking it might be something to do with it being a PostMapping? Maybe it is meant to be GetMapping or DeleteMapping?